# Unable to save Typescript files in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I recently migrated my solution from VS 2015 to VS 2017 (both in Enterprise edition) and now I'm constantly unable to save Typescript files. It works fine for a couple of first minutes and after that I'm presented with a 'Save file as' screen. I have to wait a minute or so, and I'm able to save it without problem. It seems like edited files are being locked for a random amount of time. Is this an issue with migration? Or VS 2017 in general? Any hints will be greatly appreciated.